# ConfigurationBuilder().AddEnvironmentVariables() not working on Mac

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, mono, visual-studio-mac

Having this issue with visual studio for Mac - Can't load my configured environment variables.

If i run the app from a Terminal it works, but it doesn't if i run it from Visual Studio for Mac.

I added my variables to:

1. .bashrc
2. .bash_profile

I am using Visual Studio v8.7.8

(Yes, i tried restarting visual studio, even restarting the computer).

Any help is useful.

Thanks.

**--EDIT--**

I created the same post in [Microsoft's dev community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1200692/configurationbuilderaddenvironmentvariables-not-wo.html). Hopefully they fix this on the future. Stick to running VS from a Terminal for now.

Comment: Maybe this will help you: https://placona.co.uk/osx-pro-tip-for-environment-variables/

Comment: lol it worked, now it makes sense why ti worked, but come on now... it's a developer app, something this basic shouldn't be so complicated... Anyway, Thanks man.

Comment: Yeah, weird. But I cannot explain it, since I'm not familiar with mac. Maybe you can add and accept your own answer. Make sure you add the details and not just the link. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, unfortunately Visual Studio for Mac does not support using environment variables defined via bash or zsh (yet?...).

There is a hacky workaround by launching VS from a Terminal

```
/Applications/Visual\ Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/VisualStudio &
```

Launching it this way will allow VS to access user configured variables.

To make it easier to remember, an alias can be created by:

```
alias vs='/Applications/Visual\ Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/VisualStudio &'
```

Just remember to add this line to `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc`

Here is a [Medium article](https://medium.com/@himanshuagarwal1395/setting-up-environment-variables-in-macos-sierra-f5978369b255) on how to edit these files.

Here is a [Blog post](https://placona.co.uk/osx-pro-tip-for-environment-variables/) describing the VS issue.